# Writing results of SQL query to Temp View in Databricks

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, temp-tables

I would like to create a Temporary View from the results of a SQL Query - which sounds like a basic thing to do, but I just couldn't make it work and don't understand what is wrong.

This is my SQL query - which works fine and returns Col1.

```
%sql
SELECT
  Col1
  FROM
  Table1
    WHERE EXISTS (
      select * 
        from TempView1)
```

I would like to write the results in another table which I can query. Therefore I do this :

```
df = spark.sql("""
SELECT
  Col1
  FROM
  Table1
    WHERE EXISTS (
      select * 
        from TempView1)""")
```

OK

```
df
```

Out[28]: DataFrame[Col1: bigint]

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df_tmp_view")
```

OK

```
%sql
select * from df_tmp_view
```

Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Table or view not found: df_tmp_view; line 1 pos 14;
'Project [*]
+- 'UnresolvedRelation [df_tmp_view], [], false

```
display(affected_customers_tmp_view)
```

NameError: name 'df_tmp_view' is not defined

**What am I doing wrong ?**
I don't understand the error saying that the name is not defined although I define it just one command above. Also the SQL query is working and returning data...so what am I missing ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the global context of the view, for example in your case:

```
global_temp_db = spark.conf.get("spark.sql.globalTempDatabase")
display(table(global_temp_db + "." + 'df_tmp_view'))
```

[documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebook-workflows.html)

for example:

```
df_pd = pd.DataFrame(
  {
    'Name' : [231232,12312321,3213231],
  }
)

df = spark.createDataFrame(df_pd)

df.createOrReplaceGlobalTempView('test_tmp_view')

global_temp_db = spark.conf.get("spark.sql.globalTempDatabase")
display(table(global_temp_db + "." + 'test_tmp_view'))
```